# Maple compact ludecomposition A.x=B, x is matrix

Tags: matrix, maple

I have recently implemented the LUDecomposition routine from Numerical Recipe 2nd edition called bandec(). It creates a lu decomposition with a banded matrix in compact form (it also returns the L and U in compact form). My question is, how do I solve a system of equations

A.x=B, if x is a matrix?

Is there a routine I could use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote "sparse banded". While there is no special sparse solver for the banded case, there is use of the (dense) band solvers from LAPACK. I write this on the small chance that might actually be your case.

Eg,

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra):
N:=10000:
M:=RandomMatrix(N,datatype=float[8]):
V:=RandomVector(N,datatype=float[8]):
infolevel[LinearAlgebra]:=1:
X:=CodeTools:-Usage(LinearSolve(M,V)):
  LinearSolve: using method LU
  LinearSolve: calling external function
  LinearSolve: NAG hw_f07adf
  LinearSolve: NAG hw_f07aef
  memory used=0.75GiB, alloc change=0.78GiB, cpu time=16.24s, real time=4.30s, gc time=8.00ms
Norm(M.X-V);
  unknown: NAG hw_f06paf
  unknown: NAG hw_f06paf
  Norm: calling external function
  Norm: NAG:  hw_f06raf
                                      -8
                1.06381179421077832 10  

restart;
with(LinearAlgebra):
N:=10000:
B:=max(1,floor(0.005*N)):
2*B+1;
                          101
M:=RandomMatrix(N,shape=band[B,B],datatype=float[8]):
V:=RandomVector(N,datatype=float[8]):
infolevel[LinearAlgebra]:=1:
X:=CodeTools:-Usage(LinearSolve(M,V)):
  LinearSolve: using method LU
  LinearSolve: calling external function
  LinearSolve: CLAPACK hw_dgbtrf_
  LinearSolve: CLAPACK hw_dgbtrs_
  memory used=13.09MiB, alloc change=11.52MiB, cpu time=20.00ms, real time=23.00ms, gc time=0ns
Norm(M.X-V);
  Multiply: calling external function
  Multiply: NAG hw_f06pbf
  Multiply: calling external function
  Multiply: NAG hw_f06pbf
Norm: calling external function
  Norm: NAG:  hw_f06raf
                                     -11
               8.03126454229641240 10
```

Comment: Hi! Yes this is my case thank you! I was trying matrices 1000x1000 which did not give any speed in time. It actually went slower. Only when increasing the size to 10000 did it go faster with banded. Do you know why it goes slower for smaller matrices? The matrices are really sparse so shouldn't it always go faster to solve?

Comment: Does the above code show similar timings, to compare, exactly as written? And when you change only the size to 1000 above? It's key to use datatype=float[8] on the Matrices/Vectors. That infolevel setting shows which clapack functions are used, and in the band case reveals that it uses the specialized band-LU (packed storage) from LAPACK. It'd be easier to debug if you posted as www.mapleprimes.com and uploaded an actual worksheet example into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The regular command **LinearAlgebra:-LinearSolve** handles that. If **B** is a matrix, then **x** will be also.

Comment: Yes and it works great, but I have been trying to implement a huge sparse banded matrix. All of the "sparse" methods that Maple gives has only been slower (which is weird!). That is why I tried to implement a routine that takes advantage over the fact that the banded matrix is really sparse.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your Comment and your Question. What does the sparsity of **A** have to do with whether **x** is a matrix?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was not clear. I have a sparse banded matrix J and I want to solve the system J.X=B, where X is a matrix. This can be done with LinearSolve, but it goes terribly slow. So I have been trying to implement an LUdecomposition code that takes advantage of the sparsity, but now I need a routine that does what LinearSolve does (for J.X=B above), but that is compatible with the output from bandec(), which is the PLU matrices in compact form.